# Eclipse Luna Crashing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-luna

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.10 and my eclipse Luna keep crashing abruptly. Same was happening in Ubuntu14.10. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

It just shuts down, when I try to write something, or sometimes when opening some file and sometimes keep working for and hour without creating any problem.

also added **-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla** in eclipse.ini file but no solution.

Please suggest some solution. This is very - 2 irritating. . I am unable to do any work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My solution was:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --disable silverlight
```

I found the information here: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421074/consistent-dialog-concerning-wine-silverlight)